# Creating a workbook, sending values to it, then opening it for the user

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an overflow error now with the line that inserts the date.

```
        With ActiveSheet
            Dim wbNewAudit As Workbook: Set wbNewAudit = Workbooks.Open("\\JACKSONVILLE-DC\Common\SOP's for JV\SOP Audits\2019\" & NewAuditFileName, True, True)            
            wbNewAudit.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = "SOP Title: " & .Cells(ActiveRow, 3)
            wbNewAudit.Worksheets(1).Range("E1") = "Date: " & Format(Now, “MM / dd / yyyy”)
        End With
```

Comment: What line is supposed to send the values? The last one? What values is it supposed to send? Sounds like your problem might be a reliance on `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: You're right..if I change that to a static value like 123 it sends it to the workbook fine. How should I reference the sheet that I am pulling the data from?

Comment: Just posted an edit above.

Comment: Change the quotation marks to straight quotes: `Format(Now, "MM / dd / yyyy")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the quotation marks to straight quotes: `Format(Now, "MM / dd / yyyy")` via BigBen